# i keep getting an error about .position in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So i tried making a kick command in dicors.js(creating a bot). I did a little bit of research and I ended up with copying a code from stack overflow. The code was working fine but i wanned to make it so if "x" that has a lower rank tries to kick "y" which has higher rank, the bot would then send a message to "x" that he can't kick a higher rank person. (both x and y are users)

The code that i copied also has this function included and i keep getting this error

```
let authorHighestRole = msg.member.highestRole.position;
                                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined
```

I searched online: nothing.
I tried some stupid things like adding () to .position
I searched in the Discord.js docs and still nothing.

I came to the conclusion that the code is old.

Here is my code

```
case 'kick' :
            if(msg.channel.type === 'DM') {
                msg.channel.send('This command can use only in guide');
                return;
            };
    
            if(!msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
                msg.channel.send('You have no permissions to do that');
                return;
            };
    
            let mentionMember = msg.mentions.members.first();
            if(!mentionMember) {
                msg.channel.send('Please specify the person you want to kick!');
                return;
            }
    
            if(!mentionMember.kickable) {
                msg.channel.send('I can\'t kick this user!');
                return
            };

            //Get the highest role of user for compare
            let authorHighestRole = msg.member.highestRole.position;
            let mentionHighestRole = mentionMember.highestRole.position;

            //If mention user have same or higher role, so show this error msg
            if(mentionHighestRole >= authorHighestRole) {
                msg.channel.send('You can`t kick members with equal or higher position');
                return;
            };
        
            mentionMember.kick()
                msg.channel.send(`${mentionMember.displayName} was kicked`)
        break;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `msg.member.highestRole` is `undefined`. Have you tried to check what properties the `msg.member` has?

Comment: I guess its basically the author of the message as ```mentionMember``` is the user that is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

member doesn't contain a property called highestRole, I believe the property you're looking for is: member.roles.heighest.

see docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest

```js
msg.member.roles.highest.position
```

Comment: yep this was the answer 
thank you so much for the help ;)